# How can I do Vertical Paging in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Is it possible to do vertical scrolling without horizontal scrolling in UIScrollView? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property pageEnabled should set to TRUE, for paging scroll.
The contentSize's width is as the same as view's width, and the height of contentSize set the value you desired. Then, it will do vertical scrolling, but no horizontal scrolling in UIScrollView.

You can read this sample coes, [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904). Maybe there are something you need in the sample codes.